# I am looking for a fix with a formula that I am making in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I have a website that I am making, its a spin off of universal paperclips, its called rubberbands. In the process of course you need to find a decent formula to calculate the growth in public interest with the amount of people that buy your rubberbands. So that the higher the public interest the more people buy your rubberbands.

I have got a formula that I am using but it is very subjective and flawed plus it doesnt work if your public interest goes past 800 percent. Below is the formula that I used with a 100ms interval.

```
 setInterval (function() {
       if (publicinterest < 100) {
         if (Math.random() < publicinterest / 200) {
           if (Math.random() < publicinterest / 200) {
             if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
               money += sellingprice; 
               publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / 
sellingprice;  
                 unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
                 document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 
'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
               document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 
'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
               document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = 
"Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
           }
         }
       }
     }
   if (publicinterest < 200) {
       if (Math.random() * 2 < publicinterest / 190) {
         if (Math.random() * 2 < publicinterest / 190) {
           if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
             money += sellingprice; 
             publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;
             unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
             document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
             document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
             document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
         }
       }
     }
   }

   if (publicinterest < 300) {
       if (Math.random() * 3 < publicinterest / 180) {
         if (Math.random() * 3 < publicinterest / 180) {
           if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
             money += sellingprice; 
             publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;
             unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
             document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
             document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
             document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
         }
       }
     }
   }

   if (publicinterest < 400) {
       if (Math.random() * 4 < publicinterest / 170) {
         if (Math.random() * 4 < publicinterest / 170) {
           if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
             money += sellingprice; 
             publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;
             unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
             document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
             document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
             document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
         }
       }
     }
   }

   if (publicinterest < 500) {
       if (Math.random() * 5 < publicinterest / 160) {
         if (Math.random() * 5 < publicinterest / 160) {
           if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
             money += sellingprice; 
             publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;
             unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
             document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
             document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
             document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
         }
       }
     }
   }

   if (publicinterest < 600) {
       if (Math.random() * 6 < publicinterest / 150) {
         if (Math.random() * 6 < publicinterest / 150) {
           if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
             money += sellingprice; 
             publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;
             unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
             document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
             document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
             document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
         }
       }
     }
   }

   if (publicinterest < 700) {
       if (Math.random() * 7 < publicinterest / 140) {
         if (Math.random() * 7 < publicinterest / 140) {
           if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
             money += sellingprice; 
             publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;
             unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
             document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
             document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
             document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
         }
       }
     }
   }

   if (publicinterest < 800) {
       if (Math.random() * 8 < publicinterest / 130) {
         if (Math.random() * 8 < publicinterest / 130) {

           if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
             money += sellingprice; 
             publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;
             unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
             document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' +   money.toFixed(2); 
             document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
             document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
         }
       }
     }
   }
     //console.log('sellingpriceint', sellingprice);
     //console.log('publicinterestint', publicinterest);
     //console.log('rubberbandsint', rubberbands)


 },100)
```

This code describes 4 variables. The public interest is the event that is meant to increase the amount of sales dependent on how high it is. The selling price is the amount of money that you sell the rubberbands for and therefore the lower the higher the public interest. The publicinterestdecider, is basically the margin and how I would increase the public interest with upgrades. And unsoldrubberbands is just the inventory. Money is pretty selfexplanatory. So really all that I am looking for is a better formula that will work exponentially depending on the public interest and works no matter what the public interest is. (Keep in mind, public interest itself is just a number but on the display I add a percent symbol next to it)

Comment: If you're really serious about getting this question answered, I'd recommend simplifying it by a _lot_ and probably summarising the algorithm you're trying to describe into pseudocode, then resubmitting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to make most of your code re-usable:

```
setInterval (function() {
    if (publicinterest < 100) {
        if (Math.random() < publicinterest / 200) {
            if (Math.random() < publicinterest / 200) {
                if (unsoldrubberbands > 0) {
                    money += sellingprice; 
                    publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;  
                    unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
                    document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
                    document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
                    document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(var loop = 0; loop < 7; loop++){
        if(
            publicinterest < loop * 100 + 200
            &&
            Math.random() + (loop + 2) < publicinterest / (190 - 10 * loop)
            &&
            Math.random() + (loop + 2) < publicinterest / (190 - 10 * loop)
            &&
            unsoldrubberbands > 0
        ) {
             money += sellingprice; 
             publicinterest = publicinterestdecider / sellingprice;
             unsoldrubberbands -= 1; 
             document.getElementById('moneytext').innerHTML = 'Money: $' + money.toFixed(2); 
             document.getElementById('inventory').innerHTML = 'Inventory: ' + unsoldrubberbands;
             document.getElementById('publicinterest').innerHTML = "Public Interest " + publicinterest.toFixed(1) + '%';
        }
    }

},100)
```

I'm not sure you want to run the code 7 times for each interval, but if so, this will do it.